# Creating single polygon from overlapping ones

Tags: overlapping-features, dissolve, tab

I would like to reduce the vertex count of a map by simplifying the overlapping polygons on each layer.

[image: EExample of merging overlapping polygons]

[image: Continuation of example]

The problem is the huge map size, a whole country 1GB .MAP that depicts a whole country with a precision of 50 m.

Here are two screenshots of the same area, taken at 5-second intervals while QGIS struggles to render them.

[image]

[image]

Looks like there´s mostly a huge polygon (darker green) overlapping with thousands of fragmented ones (lighter green).

I wonder if is there a script I could use so the bottommost polygon could absorb the overlapping topmost ones.

Plugins I already tried:

- 'Refactor fields' and changing the length from 32 to 5 resulted on a geometry that is lightning fast to render, but the file size is exactly the same. (I wonder why?)

[image]

- 'dissolve' fails due to invalid geometry found
- 'clean geometry plugin' gets stuck at 60% after a couple of hours
- 'v.clean' fails due to many degenerated polygons
- 'simplify' fails due to invalid geometry found
- 'fix geometry' gets stuck at 60% after a couple of hours

What specific steps should I choose, to accomplish the Dissolve of a >1GB map, without QGIS crashing or getting stuck?

Comment: Dissolve is the correct operation. You need to repair geometries. It might help to clip the sources into tiles before processing, then dissolve the tiles.

Comment: Bufferby 0 might help for geometry errors

Comment: Thank you, I'll split the map and update the results. I wonder what Bufferby 0 means on dissolving. Searched the documentation without success. Found a way to execute python code like this: processing.run("native:dissolve", {'INPUT':'C:/Cobertura/GSM COBERTURA GARANTIZADA/GSM NACIONAL GARANTIZADA 3Q2022.TAB|geometrytype=Polygon','FIELD':[],'SEPARATE_DISJOINT':False,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}) but don't know how to include the Bufferby 0 parameter.

Comment: Buffer the layer with 0 distance. Then dissolve. So two processing tools

Comment: This is still highly subjective. We don't have your data. Every large dataset has its quirks, and some problems can't be solved with some tools. There might not be any perfect answer to this combination of software and data.

Comment: Now I understand your concern Vince, thank you for the clarification. I can upload one of the maps to a public server, to make this post more useful. Do you think it's worth it?

Comment: Try the three steps [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/440360/difference-function-in-qgis-is-extremly-slow/440361#440361) then dissolve

Comment: Well, guys, I tried the ideas above, but sadly they still get stuck. Probably there´s something very wrong with the provided map. Please don't close the question, I'll keep actively looking for solutions (for this type of huge, convoluted geometries) and put them on this post, to help anyone with my same issue in the future.