# Difference function in QGIS is extremly slow

Tags: qgis, differences

I execute the `difference` function in QGIS. I have used it many times before, and it worked well.

For the final task I like to delete lines with my nationwide buffers. It is a lot, but I have had in running overnight for 10 hours, still at one percent. I have activated all core of my CPU in QGIS. I don't understand why it is taking so long. The buffer are all disovled. It is just one big layer. The funny thing is I used the wrong function (`clip`) before. It was done after 2 hours.

On what do I have to pay attention to speed this process up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Having few (or many), very large features, especially multipart geometries, make processing slow. Try:

1. [Multipart to singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgismultiparttosingleparts)
2. [Subdivide](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgissubdivide)
3. [Spatial index](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgiscreatespatialindex)

On the input layers, then try Difference again

Comment: 1) and 3) are already enough to reduce computing time to 2 minutes. thanks a lot!

Comment: I can confirm, the difference is incredible just running 1). Can somebody explain why singleparts are much quicker? It's counterintuitive to me.