# Using QGIS, what is the simplest way to find the closest point in one layer for every point in the second layer?

Tags: qgis, point, layers, knn

In QGIS, I have two layers of points (layer #1 - blue, and layer #2 - pink).
How can I find the closest point in layer #1 for each point in layer #2, and then save this new selection as its own new layer?

[image: The two point layers]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join attributes by nearest with many data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/460196/join-attributes-by-nearest-with-many-data)